# Ember Data Model attribute sanitization/escaping to prevent XSS?

Tags: ember.js, escaping, ember-data, xss, sanitization

How can I perform sanitization on string attributes to prevent XSS? Right now my thoughts are to override my base model's save method and iterate over all the strings in the model and set all the string inputs to safe strings. Would this be a good way to approach this problem or is there a better way?

EDIT:

Problem occurs when saving a name attribute ( alert('xss')) for a person in the app. It saves it in a non-sanitized manner into the database. Then that name is loaded in our other site which does not sanitize the output and that's where the script injection occurs! I'd like to sanitize it before saving it to the DB

Comment: Honestly, this sounds more like a server-side concern.  By preventing the bad data in the database no matter how it gets there, you'll have fixed the problem once.  If you have a different UI in the future, you don't want to have to sanitize there as well.

Comment: ^ I agree. This makes the most sense. Since someone malicious could post malicious requests that bypass the sanitization.

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars automatically sanitizes strings.  If you want to avoid this, you must explicitly use the triple-brace syntax:

```
{{{myHtmlString}}}
```

Comment: Problem is not script injection in the ember app. Let me edit my question so you can see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to sanitise the input, you **really** ought to change that other site to make sure it html-escapes the data it is presenting from the database. Even if you would "sanitise" things on the Ember side, can you guarantee there are no other vulnerabilities which allow someone to inject HTML in the database?

Always escaping anything being presented is really the only safe way to deal with XSS. If you're filtering input you are very likely to not catch every possible way of injecting unexpected input.

Comment: I agree with you. Though I think it's also important to escape the input if someone were to forget to escape the text elsewhere

Comment: Even if you are filtering input, you may get characters you didn't expect, character sets you didn't expect (carefully crafted to bypass the filter and yield a different result in a different character set). You'd have to have a whitelist of anything you want to let through, and that is likely to end up being too restrictive. It is much easier and safer to escape the output.

Comment: Can you give me an example of characters i wouldn't expect? If i use handlebars escaping method shouldn't I be safe?

Comment: Safe, yes. But going by https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/lib/handlebars/utils.js you'd be escaping `/[&<>"'``]/g`, and some people do have those characters in a name or street address. You're then going to be double-encoding them on output at some point, and you could end up with e.g. `O&#8217;Neil`.

Comment: I'm starting to understand your point. Though, how did you end up with 'O&#8217;Neil'? I'm assuming that was double encoded... what was it before?

Comment: Oops, would be `O&#x27;Neil` instead (as per the code) but same idea: Input gets escaped to that, that's what you would get in your database. Then on output the `&` in there is escaped to `&amp;` and `#x27;` is not special and presented as it came from the database.